# Is the activerecord pattern built into Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, activerecord, entity-framework-4, subsonic3, design-patterns

In the past I used Sub Sonic which has the activerecord pattern baked into the framework. With Sub Sonic it was very easy to find the "dirty" fields on an update. I now have a need to create an audit table in my application that utilizes Entity Framework 4. Is there a comparable feature in EF 4 that will give me the dirty fields?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can get similar functionality with what is described in this page at MSDN:

[Identity Resolution, State Management, and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx)

> **Change Tracking** -> Change tracking
>   information for the object graph is
>   stored in ObjectStateEntry objects,
>   which are created by the ObjectContext
>   for each attached object.
>   ObjectStateEntry objects store the
>   following information for the
>   entities:
>
> ...
>
> The names of the entity's modified
>   properties.
>
> **Entity State** -> The object context must know the state of an object to
>   save changes back to the data source.
>   ObjectStateEntry objects store
>   EntityState information. The
>   SaveChanges methods of the
>   ObjectContext process entities that
>   are attached to the context and update
>   the data source depending on the
>   EntityState of each object. For more
>   information, see Creating, Adding,
>   Modifying, and Deleting Objects. The
>   following table shows the possible
>   states of an object.
>
> The state of objects inside an object context is managed by the ObjectStateManager. To find out the state of an object, call one of the following ObjectStateManager methods: TryGetObjectStateEntry, GetObjectStateEntry, or GetObjectStateEntries. The State property of the ObjectStateEntry defines the state of the object.

Take a look at this article for more info:

[What's New and Cool in Entity Framework 4.0](http://www.develop.com/entityframework4)